# Googlemap not showing in ajax load page

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I am loading a page in when a button is clicked using AJAX. I have a map on my normal page that loads and displays fine but when i add the  to the loaded page it does not show up or give me any errors? I have tried to add the initmap() to the code after the ajax load but noting? Do I have to bind it or something?

What am I doing wrong?

Code for the map is :-

```
<div id='map-canvas'></div>
```

the JS

```
function initMap() {
  var pointA = new google.maps.LatLng(51.7519, -1.2578),
    pointB = new google.maps.LatLng(50.8429, -0.1313),
    myOptions = {
      zoom: 7,
      center: pointA
    },
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), myOptions),
    // Instantiate a directions service.
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService,
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
      map: map
    }),
    markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointA,
      title: "point A",
      label: "A",
      map: map
    }),
    markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pointB,
      title: "point B",
      label: "B",
      map: map
    });

  // get route from A to B
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB);

}

initMap();



function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, pointA, pointB) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: pointA,
    destination: pointB,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

the code for the button which loads the load is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mainstuff button").click(function(){
        $('#loader').show();
        status = $(this).attr("data-name");
        var new_url = "get_job_details.php?job_id="+status;
        //alert(status);
        $("#div1").load(new_url);

    });
});
```

which produces this : -

```
echo "<div id='map-canvas'></div><table class='mainTable'>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width='50%' style='vertical-align: top'><li>Pick up time : <B>".$new_date."</B></li><li>Pick up time : <B>".$p_time."</B></li><li>Pick up address : <B>".$p_address."</B></li><li>Destination address : <B>".$d_address."</B></li><li>Return date : <B>".$d_date_new."</B></li><li>Return time : <B>".$d_time."</B></li><li>Number of passengers : <B>".$pax."</B></li><li>Estimated distance : <B>".$est_dist."</B></li><li>Estimated time : <B>".$est_time."</B></li><li></li></td>
<td width='50%' id='description'><li>Purpose : <B>".$purpose."</B></li><li>Extra requirements : <B>".$list."</B></li><li>Notes : <B>".$notes."</B></li><li>Total current bids : <B>".$total_bids."</B></li><li>Current lowest bid : <B>£".$lowest_bid_price."</B></li><li>Your bids on this job : <B>".$your_bids."</B></li><li>Your current lowest bid : <B>£".$my_lowest_bid."</B></li><li>Make a new bid of : £<input id='bid_amount' type='text'><li><textarea id='extras' class='extras' placeholder='Enter any information you would like the customer to know'></textarea></li><button id='makebid' data-name='".$job_id."' type='button' class='btn btn-bid'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> MAKE BID </button></li><div id='actions'><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onclick='closedown()'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'></span> CLOSE </button></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your ajax code by adding initMap() after ajax load, for example

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".mainstuff button").click(function(){    
        var status = $(this).attr("data-name");
        $('#loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url : "get_job_details.php",
            cache: false,
            data: { 'job_id':status },
            type: 'GET', 
            success : function(data) {
                $("#div1").html(data);
                $('#loader').hide();
                initMap();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('#loader').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I did already, I have places it in a popup not which works wierdly enough but will try again at some point, thanks anyway

Comment: May be your problem is in another part, first check your status getting correctly, then check your ajax call is working fine, is it going to success part or error part ? You can trace them using an alert();